# Automatic Creation of new text lines in a JTextArea Component

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

I am using a jTextArea in a javaswing application with Netbeans 7.
 Want to make it possible to automatically create a new line 
when the text entered gets to the end of the jtextarea.
This will mean that there will not be a horizontal scrollbar.
The "enter" button will not need to be pressed 
before a new line is created

A simple illustration is like when using a word document. 
A new line is created when the user gets to the 
 end of each line of the document.

Any suggestion.

Comment: You could have found that yourself by just browsing the [javadoc of JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using

```
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
```